# Is it possible to create class that uses nullable int as generic parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, int, nullable

I am trying to create class called Stats that uses generic parameter T. I intend to use T as int? or float?. However, when I try to create object of class Stats I get that:
Error   1   The type 'int?' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method ....
Any help would be appreciated

Here's my code:

```
Stats<int?> stats = new PlayerMatchStats(); // PlayerMatchStats inherits Stats


public abstract class Stats<T> : BaseEntity where  T : struct 
{

}
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me - you can't do it.

Comment: removeThis conflicts with the `T : struct` constraint. Remove it, eventually replace it with `T : new()`.

Answer (score 4):

From [the C# programming guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx), when a generic constraint of `where T : struct` is specified "the type argument must be a value type. Any value type except Nullable can be specified."

You can make a *member* of a generic class with a struct constraint nullable, e.g.

```
public class Foo<T> where T : struct
{
   public T? SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

but you cannot provide a nullable as the closed generic type.

Answer (score 1):

[`where T : struct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) does not allow nullable types. Perhaps this refactoring is what you're after:

```
public abstract class Stats<T> where T : struct
{
    // instead of the following with T being int?
    // public abstract T Something { get; }
    // have the following with T being int
    public abstract T? Something { get; }
}
public class PlayerMatchStats : Stats<int> { ... }

// this is now valid:
Stats<int> stats = new PlayerMatchStats();
```

Or remove the `struct` constraint:

```
public abstract class Stats<T>
{
    public abstract T Something { get; }
}
public class PlayerMatchStats : Stats<int?>
{
    public override int? Something { get { return 0; } }
}

Stats<int?> stats = new PlayerMatchStats();
```